# MVC 5 limit access to folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, configuration, web-config

I have this settings in my web.config file in the root of site

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/reserved/login" timeout="2880"></forms>
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

I wnat to protect a javascript folder, I have created a web.config file in this folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

why is this ignored?
Thanks

Comment: `<deny users="*" />` ?

Comment: with <deny users="*" /> doesn't work

Comment: now with this code it works

Comment: lol sort of magic =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web.config in the root of the site add:

```
<location path="Javascript">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Alternatively you could revise it to

```
<system.web>
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/reserved/login" timeout="2880"></forms>
 </authentication>
 <authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
</system.web>
```

and whitelist folders with `allow users="*"` instead.

I don't believe a web.config is read in arbitrary locations.

Comment: Which way round, can you access nothing, or access everything? If the first, then you need to add whitelist rules, if the latter you need to properly add the deny users part.

Comment: if I deny access to all site it redirects to my login page, but I need to protct only one directory. Your first code does not work

Comment: Protect it from who? All or Unauth? Did you update the `path="Javascript"` to the correct folder name? Is it in your *root* web.config?